# Como colocar try/catch no formato ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Código:

```
 this.boxes.forEach(box => document.body.removeChild(box) );
```

Em ES5 seria:

```
 this.boxes.forEach(function (box) {
                try {
                return document.body.removeChild(box);
                } catch(e){
                    //erros
                }
            });
```

**Arquivo ES6 arrow function:**

```
 hideResizers() {
        // stop listening for image deletion or movement
        document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.checkImage);
        this.quill.root.removeEventListener('input', this.checkImage);
        // reset user-select
        this.setUserSelect('');
        this.setCursor('');
        // remove boxes
        this.boxes.forEach(box => document.body.removeChild(box) );
        // release memory
        this.dragBox = undefined;
        this.dragStartX = undefined;
        this.preDragWidth = undefined;
        this.boxes = [];
    }
```

**Como foi compilado:**

```
function hideResizers() {
            // stop listening for image deletion or movement
            document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.checkImage);
            this.quill.root.removeEventListener('input', this.checkImage);
            // reset user-select
            this.setUserSelect('');
            this.setCursor('');
            // remove boxes
            this.boxes.forEach(function (box) {
              return document.body.removeChild(box);
            });
            // release memory
            this.dragBox = undefined;
            this.dragStartX = undefined;
            this.preDragWidth = undefined;
            this.boxes = [];
        }
```

**O erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não vejo ganho algum em utilizar a notação de *arrow function* do ES6 neste caso. Por que não manter a `function`?

Comment: Porque algumas vezes está dá erro no dom... eu queria saber como fazer também, só pra aprendizado.

Comment: queria ver algo assim, sei lá; `this.boxes.forEach(box => try => catch { document.body.removeChild(box) } => e);`

Comment: Não entendi bem a pergunta. Se está fazendo um forEach significa que boxes é uma array existente, logo qual a razão de verificar se o código `document.body.removeChild(box)` irá retornar erro?

Comment: Se você já sabe que o erro acontece quando `box` não é do tipo `Node`, e quer escrever esse código de forma mais breve, porque não faz `this.boxes.forEach(box => box instanceof Node && document.body.removeChild(box) )` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A notação da *arrow function* inserida no ES6 é basicamente um açúcar sintático para quando você precisa definir uma relação 1:1 da entrada com a saída da função, extremamente útil para as funções de mapeamento.

No seu caso a relação não é 1:1, pois haverá o tratamento de exceção também, então não há vantagens em se utilizar tal notação.

Mas, caso seja apenas curiosidade de como ficaria:

```js
this.boxes.forEach(box => {
  try {
    return document.body.removeChild(box)
  } catch(e) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Ou seja, a diferença está entre digitar `function` ou `=>`. Para o tratamento de exceções não há sintaxe diferente no ES6, por isso se mantém igual a que já existia no ES5.

Comment: Assim eu sei fazer, eu queria ver na sintaxe do ES6...

Comment: @IvanFerrer Essa é a sintaxe do ES6.

Comment: Não, acho que tem formas mais resumidas de fazer isso.

Comment: Como seria mais resumido que isso?

Comment: Sei lá... essa é minha dúvida. KKKK, se eu soubesse não teria a pergunta.

Comment: Pois é, a resposta é que não há sintaxe diferente para isso no ES6. O tratamento de exceções é o mesmo que no ES5. A única coisa que poderia mudar ali é passar a função anônima para uma função *arrow*, mesmo sem fazer sentido a mudança.

Comment: Vou escolher sua resposta, porque pelo que li, é assim mesmo, valeu!

Comment: Só um adendo na resposta, a principal diferença (e vantagens) das _arrow functions_ é o contexto do objeto, por exemplo, se passar uma função anônima para um forEach de um array o contexto `this` dessa função é o array em questão, porém com arrow function o `this` continua sendo o contexto atual.

Comment: @KaduAmaral Exato, mas para o contexto da pergunta julguei que isso não seria relevante por, visto que isso também não justificaria o uso das *arrow*.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade eu solucionei assim:

```
try {
     this.boxes.forEach(box => document.body.removeChild(box) );
   } catch(e) {
   //...
}o pli
```

O problema é que eu fiz um método que remove o elemento quando eu mudava minha rota da página, e fica com a seleção sujando a outra tela, e plugin não encontrava esse elemento, pois já havia sido removido... então precisava colocar um `try { } catch () {}` só para ele passar direto quando não houver.

Comment: Mas isso não faz exatamente o mesmo que o código da pergunta. Neste caso, se `this.boxes` possuir 100 itens e der erro no primeiro, os outros 99 não serão processados. Com o `try/catch` em cada item, dentro do laço, você trata o erro de cada item separadamente.

Comment: Sim, de fato, mas é isso que estou dizendo, eu não preciso tratar os errors isoladamente, só preciso abandonar a regra... quando não houver mais seu uso. É uma gambi!